# how to dismiss current view controller while segue time in swift3

Tags: view, swift3, segue, identifier, dismiss

This is my segue method. Let's say this method is in ParentViewController.

```
override fu n c prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "subViewController" {
        // Before appears in the screen.
        let subViewController = segue.destination as! SubViewController
        subViewController.currentMarks = sender as? Int16
}
```

It is working perfect. Now coming to SubViewController. Here I'm doing some thing and I have a button here. Whenever I click this button it should dismiss SubViewController and needs to open ParentViewController (not opening because it's already opened state only).

Exactly whenever I click button in SubViewController, subViewController just needs to dismiss then automatically ParentViewController will be visible I think (because already opened one only I'm not closed right?).

How to implement like this mechanism? In SubViewController button action I have written this:

```
self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    })
```

but it didn't work. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: What kind of segue it is? modal or push one?

Comment: performSegue(withIdentifier: "subViewController", sender: currentMarks)

then 
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
{
if segue.identifier == "subViewController" {
        // Before appears in the screen.
        let subViewController = segue.destination as! SubViewController
        subViewController.currentMarks = sender as? Int16
}}

Comment: No I'm not talking about this select your segue in story board and check what kind of it is modal or push?

Comment: check whether self.navigationController is nil?
also try to use self.dismiss(animated: , completion)

Comment: sorry bro i didnt get you iam newbie to ios

 i created reference like this

let subViewController = segue.destination as! SubViewController

Answer (score 9):

If you chose **show** when you created your segue on stoyboard. Call this in your button click:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

If you chose **present modally** call this:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```